# Magento webservice API Product options

Tags: web-services, api, magento

I searched inside the documentation of the Magento webservice API but couldn't find an option to get the variants/options for a specific product. For example I have a shoe and want to know which shoe sizes the user can choose from. Is there a possibility to get these values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**for Magento SOAP API V1 you can do this:**

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$result = $client->call($session, 'product_attribute.info', '11');
var_dump ($result);

// If you don't need the session anymore
//$client->endSession($session);
```

You will get full information about a required attribute with the list of options.

---

**Example response:**

```
array
  'attribute_id' => string '11' (length=3)
  'attribute_code' => string 'new_special_price' (length=17)
  'frontend_input' => string 'text' (length=4)
  'default_value' => null
  'is_unique' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_required' => string '0' (length=1)
  'apply_to' =>
    array
      empty
  'is_configurable' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_searchable' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_comparable' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_used_for_promo_rules' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_visible_on_front' => string '0' (length=1)
  'used_in_product_listing' => string '0' (length=1)
  'frontend_label' =>
    array
      0 =>
        array
          'store_id' => int 0
          'label' => string 'special price' (length=13)
      1 =>
        array
          'store_id' => int 2
          'label' => string 'special price' (length=13)
  'scope' => string 'store' (length=5)
  'additional_fields' =>
    array
      'frontend_class' => null
      'is_html_allowed_on_front' => string '1' (length=1)
      'used_for_sort_by' => string '0' (length=1)
```

> [source](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/product_attribute.info.html)